# Getting error in php ms access database connection

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I want to go to build an application with PHP and with existing ms access. My xampp server running in local, but unfortunately my MS Access database located in other file server, previously it was running perfectly but suddenly it gives following error MSG

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1032 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'. It is already opened exclusively by another user,
or you need permission to view its data.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tbc\test.php:6 Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\tbc\test.php(6): PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={Mi...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tbc\test.php on line 6
```

My actual code is:

```
$dbNameAccess ="//Fileserver/work/access/db.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbNameAccess)) {
   // die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db_na = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbNameAccess; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

Comment: Your error message says `It is already opened exclusively by another user,
or you need permission to view its data.` Can more than one user connect and do you have permission to access the database with your credentials?

Comment: i already tried with new db and location, but same result

Comment: Do you know if anything has changed on that server since it was last working? What happens when you try connecting to the program with the same username and credentials direct?

Comment: Is the file open in another program? Try closing it and using your script then

Comment: if i put following its not working
$dbNameAccess ="db.mdb";
but if i do something like following its working:
$dbNameAccess =filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) . "/access/."db.mdb";